# Windows mobile 6 window registration failed

Tags: windows, winapi, mobile, windows-ce

When i try to deploy the code (win32 smartphone project) the registration failed error pops up and the application exits. But if i change the right side of wc.lpszMenuName to NULL everything works fine without the menu. Is this feature not supported in win mobile 6?

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    WNDCLASS wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;



    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = NULL;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;


    if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Call [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out why `RegisterClass` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [the WNDCLASS documentation for WinMo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925944.aspx)? Under the Remarks section, it specifically states:

> **lpszMenuName** is not supported and must be NULL.

I believe that what you're actually needing is [a MenuBar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158537.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot ctacke. Unfortunately i don't have enough points to vote your answer as useful.